# Standard Matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : R^3 → R^4$ be the linear transformation defined by:
$$T(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (3x_1 − 4x_2 − x_3, x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3, 6x_1 − x_2 + 5x_3, 10x_2 + 10x_3)$$
Determine the standard matrix representation of T.

Can someone please help me with this? I am not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By matrix multiplication rules, we have

$$T(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\begin{bmatrix}t_1\\t_2\\t_3\\t4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3&-4&-1\\1&2&3\\6&-1&5\\0&10&10\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$

which is the standard matrix according to the [**standard basis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis).